# How do I delete a word with Recursion and count the times it deletes?

Tags: string, if-statement, recursion, count, return

I've completed about half of my assignment where I have to count the "chickens" in a string, remove the chickens, and return the amount of times I have to remove them.

```
public static int countChickens(String word)
    {
        int val = word.indexOf("chicken");
        int count = 0;

        if(val > -1){
            count++;
            word = word.substring(val + 1);
            //I'm aware the following line doesn't work. It's my best guess.
            //word.remove.indexOf("chicken");
            val = word.indexOf("chicken");
        }
        return count;
    }
```

As is, the program counts the correct amount of chickens in the word itself. (Sending it "afunchickenhaschickenfun" returns 2.) However, I need it to be able to return 2 if I send it something like "chichickencken" because it removed the first chicken, and then the second chicken came into play. How do I do the remove part?

Comment: Recursion typically means you are calling the same function from within the function.  I don't see any recursion occuring here.

Comment: Well, originally I had a "return 1 + countChickens() + word.substring(0, val) + word.substring(val + 7)" because my friend told me to use this, but Eclipse doesn't let me do that. The countChickens bit is wrong. This one actually ran. Was that original line actually close?

Comment: Personally I would have not made countChickens a static int and would have not returned anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the teacher showed us how to do it a few days later. If I understood David Lee's code right, this is just a simplified way of what he did.

```
public static int countChickens(String word)
    {
        int val = word.indexOf("chicken");

        if(val > -1){
            return 1 + countChickens(word.substring(0, val) + word.substring(val + 7));

        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested and writen in sudo code, but should give you a better idea on a way to approach this.

```
int numberOfChickens = 0;

public void CountAndReplaceChicken(string word)
{
   int initCheck = word.indexOf("chicken");
   if (initCheck > -1)
   {
     word = word.remove.indexOf("chicken"); // not sure about the syntax in Eclipse but given you figure this part out
     numberOfChickens++;

     int recursionCheck = word.indexOf("chicken");
     if (recursionCheck > -1)
       CountAndReplaceChicken(word);
   }
}
```